# Java ASN.1 compiler

Tags: java, asn.1

Right now I'm using [BinaryNotes](http://bnotes.sourceforge.net/) to parse ASN.1 files for use in a Java project. It takes an ASN.1 definition and produces Java class(s) that let me manipulate ASN.1 files.

I've hit a wall with extension markers (...) because it doesn't support them. The source forge project page says they're coming in the next release, but the last release was nearly 2 years ago so I fear the project is dead.

Can anyone recommend an easy (and $free) replacement that does a similar thing and does support extension markers?

Comment: Wow. There's a real mismatch of old and new technologies for you. Last time I worked on ASN.1 was in the '80's

Comment: Yeah, ASN.1 is horrid, but it's required by a particularly important and inflexible 3rd party. :-(

Comment: Also, ASN.1 DER is very important (and still very actual) for cryptography, as it's (maybe) the only data format with an unique valid representation. All the X.509 PKI standard and PKCS#7/CMS envelopes and much more are all defined as ASN.1 structures.

Comment: hello Andrew, 
can you please check this question of mine on asn.1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166482/asn1c-runtime-library-not-getting-generated and give me any help if possible? thanks..

Comment: @andreyne - Where I work we generally just use XML encoding. I suspect we aren't alone in that.

Comment: It's also used heavily in mobile telecoms (3G, 4G), LDAP, SNMP, all very much current technology. XML backed by an XSD schema is ok.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).

From the site:

> Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs for Java consist of the following:
>
> - A lightweight cryptography API.
> - A provider for the Java Cryptography Extension and the Java Cryptography Architecture.
> - A clean room implementation of the JCE 1.2.1.
> - A library for reading and writing encoded ***ASN.1*** objects.
> - ...

Comment: I'll check that out, Marcelo.

Comment: Confirmed, bouncycastle should be your first stop for ASN.1 parsing. It does not map to Java classes in the way that JAXB does for XML but rather it generates a tree structure you can traverse.

Comment: I agree with Marcelo.  I've pulled the BouncyCastle ASN.1 classes out into a separate library that I use whenever I need to parse ASN.1 structures, and it's very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Binary Notes is unsupported, but you can try [jASN1](https://www.openmuc.org/asn1/) from OpenMuc. It appears to be based in part on Binary Notes and is currently active. The `jASN1` libraries are available for download on their home page, and on JCenter and Maven Central under the group `org.openmuc`