# Java Pojo Classes -> ASN.1 for RPC

Tags: java, rpc, asn.1

I would like to do some RPC with the format of the messages being directly defined from Java interfaces, then I want to use some tools to generate the ASN.1 files.

1. Do you know what tools I can use? (if possible, something that doesn't force me to use any type from an ASN library in the interfaces which describe the format.
2. Do you know if there are libraries to do RPC with ASN.1 in a JavaSE program?

Comment: Have you seen the question on [Java ASN.1 compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968236/java-asn-1-compiler) ?

Comment: Yes, but it is not what I am asking.

Comment: What is the ASN.1 encoding representing? Are you using ASN.1 for serialization? Is the RPC on the same machine, networked, or location agnostic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that **annotating the classes and writing annotation processor producing ASN** could be a way but I can't guess amount of work it will take.

Comment: That's a way if I want to do it myself (and I can, I have a piece of code that does something similar), but I am looking for something that already exists.

Comment: I didn't find anything already existing, so I accept this answer as the solution.

Comment: I am pleased by the acceptance although I wish you would have found something.

Answer (score 1):

i think you already checked

- BinaryNotes
- Bouncy Castle
  except
- PowerASN

you want something like spring remote exporters, but no such facility exists. it would be a hot project may be called ASNExporter , if you started one using netty, mina, pure NIO, OIO, bouncycastle, spring, AOP.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I checked some of them, but didn't find what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [Java Web Services Developer Pack 2.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webservicespack-jsp-140788.html) that includes Fast Infoset 1.0.1 FCS release acceleration technology built on ASN.1 standards. Fast Infosets is quite interesting piece of technology that was started by SUN Microsystems few years ago and still available in Glassfish that has superseded JWSDP.

In general Fast Infoset implementats SAX and StAX interfaces. This allows **any** XML technologies to be used with Fast Infoset provided that they support either SAX or StAX. So it's generally that easy to have Java objects marshalled to and unmarshalled from ASN.1. On one of the conferences Fast Infoset was also referred as *binary XML*.

So you can annotate your POJOs with JAXB annotations and marchall to ASN.1 with JAXB, or you can use less intrusive library like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) to accomplish the same.

Few links:

- http://fi.java.net/how-to-use.html
- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/09/using_fastinfos.html

Comment: Thank you for it doesn't answer my very specific question, where the input is a "java source file containing a class with fields" and the output a "Asn.1 file".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the Apache Harmony project](http://harmony.apache.org/subcomponents/classlibrary/asn1_framework.html).

The website says:

> The ASN.1 framework provides a common, easy and efficient approach for working with ASN.1 basic types, notations and encoding rules. This framework can be described as a layer between a Java* object and its ASN.1 encoded form, as shown in Figure 1.

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I saw this project already, but I didn't see anywhere that you can "generate ASN.1 from Java classes". This specific operation is the subject of my question.